# Ideas on calculating the volume of $K:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^{3}: x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1, x^2+y^2\leq a\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, volume

Calculate the volume of $K:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^{3}: x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1, x^2+y^2\leq a\}$ and note that $0 < a < 1$

My ideas:

depending on the size $a$, I have a cylinder whose height is restricted by the radius of the unit sphere.

$\lambda^{3}(K)=\int_{K}d\lambda^{3}=\int_{[0,2\pi]}\int_{[0,a]}\int_{[-\sqrt{1-a},\sqrt{1-a}]}rdzdrd\phi=4\pi \sqrt{1-a}\int_{[0,a]}rdr=4\pi\sqrt{1-a}\frac{1}{2}a^2=2\pi a^2 \sqrt{1-a}$

Is this correct?

Note: if $a = 1$, I will use $\lambda^{2}$ and in this case $\lambda^{2}(K)=\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: For me it is fine.

Comment: Without even looking at the work, something must be wrong here. As $a \to 1$, the answer should tend to the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb R^3$. But your answer is $0$ when $a=1$. The limits in the $z$-integral need to dependon $r$, because for different $r$ values, there is a different height. It would be very helpful to draw a picture here.

Comment: Your answer implies that when $a=1$ the volume is $0$.

Comment: Surely this would be the case (if $a=1$) under $\lambda^{3}$ because $\mathbb R^{2}\times\{0\}$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb R^{3}$

Comment: The problem with your work is that you should take the z limits to be $\pm \sqrt{1-r^2}$, not $\pm \sqrt{1-a^2}$.  If you correct the limits of integration, you’ll get the same answer as John Wayland Bales did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solid of revolution so can be found using the cylindrical shell method

$$2\int_0^{\sqrt{a}}2\pi rh\,dx$$

where $r=x$ and $h=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Note that this is an elementary integral and you will get the result

$$ V=\frac{4\pi}{3}\left[1-(1-a)^{3/2}\right] $$